# Enterprise subscription enquiry

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

We're doing some development for a company who is looking to use the Enterprise subscription to 'test' the app on a selected group of its users, privately. 
Number of users - circa 500 
These 500 will be tightly controlled in 10 'centres' or classes.
they have a DUNS no, and this app will not be sold. (unlike the previous post on this board)
From the testing and feedback of V1, it will lead onto the release of v2 on the App store, like any other app, price TBD (if any).

So, the question.
by doing this, are we overtly flouting Apple's T&C? 
I spoke to an Apple guy in the help centre here in the UK, and he said this was kind of a grey area, but concern is that the company has a high profile. 
Can you give any guidance?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought that an Apple representative would be your definitive source of information, either that or take legal advice on the agreement you have committed to.